# Solr Start Service not working

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

I am was trying to install Solr. I have followed all the steps specified. But I am getting an error in power shell like this below.Could you please let me know what must have went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Start-Service : Failed to start service ‘solr-7.2.1 (solr-7.2.1)’.
At C:\resourcefiles\01_InstallSolr_ByJeremyDavis.ps1:155 char:5
+ Start-Service “$solrName”
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: Do you see that service installed in Windows Services?

Comment: Check the version of Java you have installed vs the version specified when adding the service.

Comment: This can also happen if you have another service using the same port. For example, if you have previously installed Solr on port 8983, you will need to install this instance on a new port.

Answer (score 8):

If you used a script to install it, the script requires you to specify a JRE version. If that version does not match the version installed, it acts this way.

If you use [Jeremy Davis' easy solr script](https://gist.github.com/jermdavis/8d8a79f680505f1074153f02f70b9105), you have to specify the version as a variable

`$JREVersion = "1.8.0_201"`

If you look on your hard drive, in program files look for the JRE version. Make sure it matched the version it was when you ran it.

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201`

If it does not match, edit the JAVA_HOME path in your windows environmental variables. Then start SOLR again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My Java_Home path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141 which I already updated when I first ran the script. It still does not work. I have tried to resume the service but I get this error
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZv8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZv8.png)

Comment: Check the Windows logs, you could able to find the exact issue. Alternatively you can try start the solr from command prompt and see whether it works. [just to make sure your solr files and setup are not corrupted] Navigate to the bin folder in cmd and start the solr "solr.cmd start". This will start Solr in port 8983 and then try navigate the admin console https://localhost:8983/solr

Comment: Resolved the issue myself. Issue was that my browser was 64 bit and JAVA JRE was 32 bit. I downloaded the 64 bit JAVA JRE for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue myself. Issue was that my browser was 64 bit and JAVA JRE was 32 bit. I downloaded the 64 bit JAVA JRE for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the simplest method for resolving issues with starting the service can be found by reviewing Event Viewer on Windows.

### Event Viewer

1. Review `Windows Logs` > `Application`
2. Find records with a `Source` of nssm

[image: Event Viewer NSSM]

3. Select the records with a `Level` of `Information`

[image: NSSM Information Level]

This lets you see the command NSSM is attempting to execute. In the screenshot above, the key piece of information is `C:\solr\solr-8.1.1-930\bin\solr.cmd -f -p 8110`

4. Enter this command into Command Prompt to find the specific exception

[image: Java Exception]

In my case, I was pointing at the wrong version of Java than what I had installed. I updated my `$JREPath` variable in my script, then removed the previous install attempt.

#### Remove Previous Install

1. From Command Prompt (administrator) run `sc delete <service name>`. You will need to ensure the service is `Stopped` for it to be deleted. If it is `Paused`, it is not fully deleted.
2. Delete Solr directory. In my case `C:\solr\solr-8.1.1-930`

After rerunning, my install succeeded.